# SQL stored procedure to get a user object and then update the values of that object

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I am looking to make a single SQL statement to select an object from the database and then update that object based on values entered through a form.

I am not used to writing advanced SQL queries and am used to ORM syntaxes, but I would like to get this right.

Currently my query looks like this

```
DECLARE @person;
SET @person = (
select u.*
from
dbo.people as u
inner join dbo.people as pe on pe.people_id = u.people_id
inner join dbo.parties as pa on pa.people_id = pe.people_id
inner join dbo.contact_details as cd on cd.parties_id = pa.parties_id
inner join enum.contact_details_types cdt on cdt.contact_details_types_id = cd.contact_details_types_id
where
u.people_id = 57121526-03e3-4dc2-bfb8-6c6fc84a9de8 #UUID of the user eg)


  UPDATE @person
  SET 
  sexes_id=test
  marital_states_id=test
  employment_states_id=test
  linkedins_id=test
  facebooks_id=test
  first_names=test
  surnames=test
  name_to_call_user=test
  id_number=test
  passport_number=test
  birth_date=test
  tax_number=test
  vat_number=test
  message_to_show_on_user_invoice=test
  workplace_name=test
```

I have been reading up about stored proceedures and know that I need to create something more than just a simple insert into query.

**ASK:**
 My question is, how do I create a query that will select this user as an object allowing the values in the database to be altered with an update statement?

**Error i am getting:**
My current error is that I cannot declare person in this way. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which table do you want to update, and what values do you want to update to this table?

Comment: I want to update the "u" table with sexes_id=test ... workplace_name=test

Comment: Where the u.people_id is equal to the uuid from the select statement

Comment: `test` is string or what?

Comment: yes, just a string to make the insert happen, once I have done that, I am going to replace with ? and do validation on the table

Comment: And you used two different schema `dbo` and `enum`?

Comment: That is correct yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need this, try it.

```
update dbo.people u
inner join dbo.people as pe on pe.people_id = u.people_id
inner join dbo.parties as pa on pa.people_id = pe.people_id
inner join dbo.contact_details as cd on cd.parties_id = pa.parties_id
inner join `enum`.contact_details_types cdt on cdt.contact_details_types_id = cd.contact_details_types_id
on u.people_id = 57121526-03e3-4dc2-bfb8-6c6fc84a9de8'
set
    u.sexes_id = ?,
    u.marital_states_id = ?,
    u.employment_states_id = ?,
    u.linkedins_id = ?,
    u.facebooks_id = ?,
    u.first_names = ?,
    u.surnames = ?,
    u.name_to_call_user = ?,
    u.id_number = ?,
    u.passport_number = ?,
    u.birth_date = ?,
    u.tax_number = ?,
    u.vat_number = ?,
    u.message_to_show_on_user_invoice = ?,
    u.workplace_name = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was over complicating the idea. Simple approach that works.